# Sorting pipeline erases the file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

After executing the command `cat mydata.txt | sort | uniq | > mydata.txt`,  why is the mydata.txt file null?

Comment: Your command dont make sense

Comment: because `| >` is a typo. Pretty sure you mean `cat mydata.txt | sort | uniq > mydata.txt`

Comment: Try `cat mydata.txt | sort | uniq > mydata.tx`

Comment: you need a temporary file (or get rid of the current temporary file).

Comment: No need for `cat` here, by the way... just use `sort mydata.txt | ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the blank between `|` and `> mydata.txt` piped the output of uniq into nothing and sent that to the  file.

Even if you had a command after the last `|`, it would still write to mydata while reading from it, which is bad and may delete most of the contents.

In Linux shells, a pipelines of commands is not executed sequentially.  All are executed simultaneously, and the output of one command is attached to the input of the next command.

You can confirm the simulataneous operation by watching what your computer is running from another terminal window, using utilities like `top` or `pstree`

Therefore, as commenters have suggested, you should use a temporary file as output.  Once the output is created, move it back to the original name, erasing it.

Like this:

```
cat mydata.txt | sort | uniq > tmp-mydata.txt
mv tmp-mydata.txt mydata.txt
```

Or as @tripleee suggests, the sort command already has uniq functionality, and one can use this command:

`sort -u -o mydata.txt mydata.txt`

Generally, writing to the file you are reading from is unsafe, but perhaps here sort is storing something internally.

Comment: Or just `sort -u -o mydata.txt mydata.txt`

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. How would one know that is safe, except experience/testing?  The man page here says only that -o sets the output file.

Comment: If you find a bug, report it.

Comment: @Paul I think you would know it's safe because, if you think about it, `sort` is obliged to read the whole file before it can output anything...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I had surmised from tripleee's remark that once upon a time, someone may have complained about not being able to sort a file in place, and so either the -o was added or fixed.

Comment: @Paul Thank you very much! I think your words 'In Linux shells, a pipelines of commands is not executed sequentially. All are executed simultaneously, and the output of one command is attached to the input of the next command.' is the key of my problem!

Comment: Glad that helped you.  If you decide that you want to accept this answer, you can click the checkmark next to it.